# Using facebook graph api not returning photo url link

Tags: php, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API. I want to get a photo url by `post_id` but it is not returning a photo url link. Actually I want to use that link for further operations. Can some body solve this problem please?

my code is:

```
$response1 = Facebook::post('/me/photos', $data);
                $response = $response1->getGraphUser()->asArray();
                $graphNode = $response1->getGraphNode();
                $post_id = $graphNode['id'];

                $getImageLink = Facebook::get('/' . $post_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying with you code, I just think it's plainly wrong. You need to specify the fields you want to retrieve. This is well documented, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile